# How to append a string to a bash command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-alias

I am sure this is a recurrent question but I failed to find one that had an answer that would fit my problem.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
alias disexit = " & disown & exit"
gnome-calculator disexit
```

So it would run the command line

```
gnome-calculator & disown & exit
```

Therefore as a result it would have an instance of the calculator running and no terminal floating behind it, without having to manually write the whole thing.

If possible, I'd like to have that alias to be permanent.

Comment: For future reference, novice users etc. it's good to explain why your alias doesn't work. It's because alias name needs to be the first word of a simple command.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how `alias` works (and AFAIK what you want can't be done without modifying `bash` itself), but if you don't mind a slightly different syntax, you can add something like

```
disexit(){
    "$@" & disown & exit
}
```

to your `.bashrc` (to make this function permanent), and call it as

```
disexit gnome-calculator
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your answer appearing while I was typing mine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with an alias. What you can do, however, is to code a function:

```
disexit() { "$1" & disown & exit; }
```

But you will need to call this the other way round:

```
disexit gnome-calculator
```

This is the closest you'll get to your requirements with `bash` syntax.

To make it permanently available, simply add the function definition to `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just run `nohup` before the desired command? As in

```
nohup gnome-calculator &
```